# Facebook Feed on web page infinte scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use **[this](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/)** plugin to create an infinite scroll effect for Facebook feeds, now I get access to the feed I need through the graph api (fan page wall posts) and I limit it to 10, and even so Facebook supplies a next and previous links to the next or previous 10 posts in the actual json data, but I just can't seem to get this plugin working with it.

Heres an example of the json data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "393459637370574_326418557474553",
         "from": {
            "category": "Consulting/business services",
            "name": "Global Georgia",
            "id": "393459637370574"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Global Georgia Tour",
                  "start_time": "2012-12-05",
                  "location": "Republic of Georgia",
                  "id": "297926606990415"
               }
            ]
         },
         "message": "What a lovely trip it was!",
         "picture": "http://photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/205700_468134469903090_2092776360_s.jpg",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=468134469903090&set=oa.462645617136057&type=1&relevant_count=4",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "photo",
         "object_id": "468134469903090",
         "created_time": 1359555861,
         "updated_time": 1359555861,
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Mareleen du Plessis",
                  "id": "1382224862"
               }
            ],
            "count": 1
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "393459637370574_333589073411971",
         "from": {
            "category": "Consulting/business services",
            "name": "Global Georgia",
            "id": "393459637370574"
         },
         "story": "Global Georgia shared a link.",
         "story_tags": {
            "0": [
               {
                  "id": "393459637370574",
                  "name": "Global Georgia",
                  "offset": 0,
                  "length": 14,
                  "type": "page"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCwYiOOZnd4DK5_&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Frsa.mfa.gov.ge\u00252FuniInc.php\u00253Fmode\u00253Dimg\u002526src_jpg\u00253Dfiles\u00252Frsa\u00252FPresentation_Credentials_to_President_Jacob_Zuma_of_South_Africa-29.01.2013.jpg\u002526im_new_w\u00253D200",
         "link": "http://rsa.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=913&info_id=16905",
         "name": "News - Embassy of Georgia to the Republic of South Africa",
         "caption": "rsa.mfa.gov.ge",
         "description": "On January 2013, in Pretoria, the firstAmbassador Extraordinary and Plenipotentiary of Georgia in the Republic of South Africa, Mr Beka Dvali presented his credentials to the President of the Republic of South Africa, H.E. Mr Jacob Zuma. ",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "link",
         "status_type": "shared_story",
         "created_time": 1359550985,
         "updated_time": 1359550985,
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Ivan A Meyer",
                  "id": "100000016287990"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Amanda Aldum",
                  "id": "779374234"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Cazz Bouwer",
                  "id": "100001702505460"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Gigi Mikeladze",
                  "id": "100004658262461"
               }
            ],
            "count": 4
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "393459637370574_450229665031926",
         "from": {
            "category": "Consulting/business services",
            "name": "Global Georgia",
            "id": "393459637370574"
         },
         "story": "Global Georgia shared Embassy of Georgia in the Republic of South Africa's photo.",
         "story_tags": {
            "0": [
               {
                  "id": "393459637370574",
                  "name": "Global Georgia",
                  "offset": 0,
                  "length": 14,
                  "type": "page"
               }
            ],
            "22": [
               {
                  "id": "340928409306379",
                  "name": "Embassy of Georgia in the Republic of South Africa",
                  "offset": 22,
                  "length": 50,
                  "type": "page"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/385189_475566662509219_1872863393_s.jpg",
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=475566662509219&set=a.405386502860569.99241.340928409306379&type=1",
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "caption": "Information on the meeting of the Ambassador of Georgia\r\nwith the National Librarian and Chief Executive Officer\r\nof the National Library of South Africa\r\n\r\nOn 24 January 2013 H.E. Mr Beka Dvali, Ambassador of Georgia held a meeting with Mr John Tsebe, the National Librarian and Chief Executive Officer of  the National Library of the Republic of South Africa, and the Chair of the Conference of Directors of National Libraries (CDNL)).\r\nAmbassador of Georgia passed on Mr Tsebe several books to be catalogued as the first ever publications on Georgia at the National Library of South Africa.\r\nDuring the meeting, the parties discussed the possibilities of cooperation between the national libraries of the two countries, the issues of supplying Georgian and Georgia-related books, by the support of the Embassy, to the National Library of South Africa as well as the prospects of hosting by the library a  literature event featuring contemporary Georgian author(s). \r\n\r\n24 January 2013\r\nPretoria",
         "properties": [
            {
               "name": "By",
               "text": "Embassy of Georgia in the Republic of South Africa",
               "href": "https://www.facebook.com/EmbassyOfGeorgia?ref=stream"
            }
         ],
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
         "privacy": {
            "value": ""
         },
         "type": "photo",
         "status_type": "shared_story",
         "object_id": "475566662509219",
         "application": {
            "name": "Photos",
            "id": "2305272732"
         },
         "created_time": 1359387805,
         "updated_time": 1359387805,
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/393459637370574/feed?limit=3&date_format=U&access_token=XXXX&since=1359555861&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/393459637370574/feed?limit=3&date_format=U&access_token=XXXX&until=1359387804"
   }
}
```

How would I get this functionality working?

Any help/advice greatly appreciated

Comment: how is this different from just using facebook.com? by the way, there's no built in way to read the json-file. You have to parse it on every scroll-load.

Comment: well i need to embed this onto a website... and that's very true, thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'd have to spend a lot of time wrangling with infinite-scroll.js to get it to do what you want, because it depends on having pagination links in your HTML.

What would probably be easier would be to write your own Javascript to detect when the user is scrolling and automatically load stuff then, based on the next page link in your most recent JSON response.

If you look at the code for [jscroll.js](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/blob/master/jquery.jscroll.js) (a similar plugin to infinte-scroll, but with code that's a bit simpler) you'll probably a get a good idea of what to look for and when to load new content. Specifically, from line 84:

```
    // Observe the scroll event for when to trigger the next load
    function _observe() {
        var $inner = $e.find('div.jscroll-inner').first(),
            data = $e.data('jscroll'),
            iContainerTop = parseInt($e.css('paddingTop')) + parseInt($e.css('borderTopWidth')),
            iTopHeight = _isWindow ? _$scroll.scrollTop() : $e.offset().top,
            innerTop = $inner.length ? $inner.offset().top : 0,
            iTotalHeight = Math.ceil(iTopHeight - innerTop + _$scroll.height() + iContainerTop),
            nextHref = $.trim(data.nextHref + ' ' + _options.contentSelector);

        if (_checkNextHref(data) && !data.waiting && iTotalHeight + _options.padding >= $inner.outerHeight()) {
            _debug('info', 'jScroll:', $inner.outerHeight() - iTotalHeight, 'from bottom. Loading next request...');
            return _load();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, It seems to allow a functionality where it calls the link in the href via AJAX and returns the response to you.

If you make an initial call on pageload to populate your initial feed, then create a display: none link with something like:

```
#nextLink {
   display: none;
}
```

and give it a href of the data['paging']['next'] then you could initialise the infinite scroll with something like:

```
$('.feedContainer').infinitescroll({
  // other options
  nextSelector: "a#nextLink",
  dataType: 'json',
  appendCallback: false
}, function(json, opts) {
    // Update your next link to point to the next page
    $('#nextLink').attr('href',json['data']['paging']['next']);

    // Add your new feed rows here
    var htmlStr = '<li>FeedContent</li>';

    // Append it to the container
    $('.feedContainer').append(htmlStr);
});
```

Use dataType 'jsonp' if it supports it.

That should roughly give you what you're looking for!